How to lazy mount a named volume in docker compose?
I'm trying to create two instances: a MySQL server and a Samba server. I want to share files from the Samba server to the MySQL server. As I have seen from the docs, Docker provides named volumes which can work under the CIFS protocol. In Docker Compose, the volumes are created on top of the build, as I can understand. How can I initialize it lazily?
For example i have the given docker compose:
services:
  samba:
    container_name: samba
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile.samba
      target: samba
      args:
        TOTAL_SAMBA_USERS: ${TOTAL_SAMBA_USERS}
        SAMBA_USER_1: ${SAMBA_USER_1}
        SAMBA_PASSWORD_1: ${SAMBA_PASSWORD_1}
        SAMBA_USER_2: ${SAMBA_USER_2}
        SAMBA_PASSWORD_2: ${SAMBA_PASSWORD_2}
        COMMON_NAME_CA: ${COMMON_NAME_CA}
        COMMON_NAME_SERVER: ${COMMON_NAME_SERVER}
        COMMON_NAME_CLIENT: ${COMMON_NAME_CLIENT}
        COUNTRY: ${COUNTRY}
        STATE: ${STATE}
        LOCALITY: ${LOCALITY}
        ORGANIZATION: ${ORGANIZATION}
        ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT: ${ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT}
        EMAIL_ADDRESS: ${EMAIL_ADDRESS}
        KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 445:445
      - 139:139
    volumes:
      - ./smb.conf:/etc/samba/smb.conf
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "smbclient", "//localhost/cert_share", "-U", "admin%1234", "-c", "ls"]
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3


  mysql-db:
    container_name: mysql-db
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile.mysql
      target: mysql
      args:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/cert
    depends_on:
      samba:
        condition: service_healthy


volumes:
  data:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=admin,password=1234
      device: //localhost/cert_share/ 

I was expecting Docker to mount accordingly based on the dependencies specified with depends_on. However, as you can see below, I receive an error message from the daemon:
 ✔ Container samba            Created                                                                                                  
 ⠋ Container mysql-db         Creating                                                                                                 0.0s 
Error response from daemon: failed to populate volume: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ssl-sample_data/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //127.0.0.1/cert_share/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ssl-sample_data/_data, data: username=admin,password=********: connection refused

